# system () in stdio or stdlib?

Tags: c, stdio, std

I used the `system("pause")` with `stdio.h` and it worked without error. When I looked at the stdio functions, `system()` is in stdlib. How come it worked, and here is the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n" );
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800102/not-including-stdlib-h-does-not-produce-any-compiler-error

Comment: You have to understand the fundamental difference between "if" and "only if". Standard documents usually say, "If you do X, you get Y." That *does not say anything* about what happens if you *don't* do X.

Comment: Generally it's better to avoid using system calls [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900666/system-calls-in-c-and-their-roles-in-programming)<br>[link](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html)<br> Calling system in windows is basically the same as running cmd.exe and typing pause.

Comment: @KerrekSB, in C an header must provide only the declarations and definitions it has to (in C++ an header can provide more).

Comment: @AProgrammer: Very interesting, thanks! I guess that makes sense, since there are no namespaces and you don't want to permit silent pollution with names you didn't expect.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I think it also has to do with template definitions dragging in implementation details.

Comment: As an aside, `system` considered harmful...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is that it's an implicit declaration. If the compiler doesn't see a prototype for a function, it assumes it was declared like:

```
int system();
```

If you turn up the warning level on your compiler, you'll likely see that this causes a warning. Implicit declarations are generally undesirable, but in this case it's why this works without causing any errors.

Comment: The current C language does not have implicit declarations. The compiler should give an error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manpages, it is in `stdlib.h`

Answer (score 0):

`#include` only carries the function declaration (prototype), the functionality is provided by a library, that's included in the linking stage.

Even if you do not `#include` it, as far as the definition assumed by the compiler when compiling matches the one in the library carrying it, there is no error and it will work.

Comment: the prototype is a *declaration*, not a *definition*. The definition is provided by the C library in this case.

Comment: you're right, my bad. read that as `s/definition/declaration/`.

Comment: @njsg: please feel free to edit your answer and correct the error

Answer (score 0):

From the Standard at 4.10.4.5 The system function is in stdlib.h:

```
     #include <stdlib.h>
     int system(const char *string);
```