# How does atoi() function works without including standard library?

Tags: c

I am using the `atoi()` function which I know is a part of `stdlib.h`.
Then why is the following code working correctly when I have not included the required header file?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_wARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    char y[10] = "1234";
    int z = atoi(y);
    printf("%d\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you will find answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800102/not-including-stdlib-h-does-not-produce-any-compiler-error

Answer (score 3):

If the compiler detects a function in use, not being prototyped, it assumes `int` as return value. Lucky `atoi()` returns  `ìnt`, so as the Standard Library is linked by default the symbol `atoi()` is resolved by the linker successfully.

If you'd had made your compiler log warnings (options `-Wall -Wextras -pedantic` for gcc) it would have notified you about the missing prototype for `atoi()`.

---

Btw: It should be

```
int main(void)
```

at least.