# Pointers, lists and voids

Tags: c, list, pointers, void-pointers

I'm trying to write a simple list. I have the next code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct _anObject {
  void* data;
  struct _anObject* previous;
  struct _anObject* next;
} object_t;


typedef struct _aHead {
  object_t* first;
  object_t* current;
  object_t* next;
  object_t* last;
  int index;
  int size;
} head_t;

head_t* new_list(void)
{
    head_t* list = malloc(sizeof(head_t));
    list->first = NULL;
    list->current = NULL;
    list->last = NULL;
    list->index = -1;
    list->size = 0;
    return list;
 }

void add_object_to_list(head_t* list, object_t* object)
{
    if (list->size == 0)
    {
    object->next = NULL;
    object->previous = NULL;
    list->first = object;
    list->current = object;
    list->last = object;
    list->index = 0;
    list->size = 1;
    } 
    else if (list->size > 0)
    {
    object->previous = list->last;
    object->next = NULL;
    list->current->next = object;
    list->current = object;
    list->last = object;
    list->size +=1;
    list->index = list->size - 1;
    }       
}

object_t* createIntObject(int value)
{
    int* data = &value;
    object_t* object = malloc(sizeof(object_t));
    object->data = data;
    return object;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    head_t* list = new_list();
    object_t* obj;
    obj = createIntObject(22);
    add_object_to_list(list, obj);
    obj = createIntObject(44);
    add_object_to_list(list, obj);

    fprintf(stderr, "size number: %i\n", list->size);
    fprintf(stderr, "First data value on the list: %i\n", *(int*) list->first->data);
    fprintf(stderr, "Last data value on the list: %i\n", *(int*) list->last->data);

    free(list);
    free(obj);
    return 0;
 }
```

I compiled without any warning or error, but when I run the code I obtain the next and not wanted result:

```
size number: 2
Current data value on the list: 0
Current data value on the list: 0
```

What am i doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Vote to close: This problem could be solved (or at least identified) by stepping through your code in the debugger.

Answer (score 5):

The error is in `createIntObject`, where you return a pointer to a function parameter:

```
object_t* createIntObject(int value) { /* deobfuscated */
    object_t* object = malloc(sizeof(object_t));
    object->data = &value; // <--
    return object;
}
```

Accessing pointers to local variables (including the function parameters) once the function has returned yields undefined behavior. Instead, allocate space for the integer value with `malloc`, and assign that to `object->data`.

This is a common beginner mistake. For more information, refer to the [reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) or the [local-variables tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/local-variables).

A couple of other notes: If you use `printf` and `malloc`, you [must](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336814/why-include-stdio-h-is-not-required-to-use-printf) `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Make sure your compiler is set to recognize these errors by default. For example, unless you are absolutely certain of compiler internals and the C standard, it's a good idea to compile your programs with `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror`.

Also, a successful program returns 0 by convention, and an error code otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

If it is any consolation (I doubt if it is), when I compile your code on MacOS X 10.7.2 with GCC 4.2.1 (LLVM), I get:

```
size number: 2
First data value on the list: 22
Last data value on the list: 44
```

All I did was add `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`, make the functions static, and declare `int main(void)` since the arguments are unused.

So, why might you not be seeing this?

- Think about where the value is stored when you take the address of it in `createIntObject()`.

Also, when you create the object, you should set the links to NULL - make sure you completely initialize the object.

Answer (score 0):

This code works well

```
object_t* createInt(int value)
{
    object_t* object = malloc(sizeof(object_t));
    object->data = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *(int*)object->data = value;
    object->next = NULL;
    object->previous = NULL;
    return object;
}
```