# Using printf function without actually importing stdio.h and it worked?! Why is that so?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why #include <stdio.h> is *not* required to use printf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336814/why-include-stdio-h-is-not-required-to-use-printf)

```
//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <conio.h>

main(){

printf("Hi");
getch();

}
```

As I was programming this, it shocked me that it worked without actually importing any c libraries such as stdio that contains the printf function. Why is that so? (Used Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2, saved as .c, not .cpp)

Answer (score 8):

C allows you to call functions without first defining the prototypes.  (C++ does not do this.)  An implicit prototype for `printf` will be defined as follows:

```
int printf();
```

Coincidentally, the calling conventions for this implicit prototype matched the actual calling conventions for `printf` on your platform.

In general, you cannot count on this working, and there are a large number of cases where it won't work.  I recommend enabling compiler warnings to detect implicit prototype declarations so you can fix them (by including the correct header).

**Footnote:** `#include` does not import libraries, it merely pastes files into your source code at compile time.  The `<stdio.h>` header contains (directly or indirectly) certain prototypes, but the library has to be linked in separately.  Since `printf` is usually in a library that is linked to programs by default, you usually don't have to do anything to use `printf`.

Comment: Yes and no. For C89/90 the program will normally "compile". But remember that `printf` is a *variadic* function. Calling a variadic function without a prototype leads to *undefined behavior*. In that sense, C language does not really "allow" one to call `printf` without a prototype. Of course, C99 language will not even compile a call to an undeclared function.

Comment: @AndreyT: Yes, that's why I said "coincidentally ... on your platform", and "you cannot count on this working".

Answer (score 4):

The `#include` preprocessor directive does not *import* any library; there is no such notion of *import* in the definition of the *C* language.

You just happen to call a function named `printf` and the standard *C* library (e.g. `libc.so` on Linux, I don't know how Windows call it) happens to be linked in by default. Since you call a function by a name known to that library, it gets linked, and is being called at runtime.

However, you should enable all warnings in you compiler, and it would warn that you call an undeclared function.