# C/C++ program without header files

Tags: c++, c, header-files

I was wondering if there is any possible way to write `C/C++` program **without using header files** at all.

```
#include <iostream.h> //I want this same code to work without including this line
#include <conio.h>    //I want this same code to work without including this line

int main ()
{
  clrscr();
  char str [80];
  int num;
  cout<<"Enter the string : "<<str;
  cin>>str;
  cout<<"Enter the number : "<<num;
  cin>>num;
  getch();  
  return 0;
}
```

I learned that in `C` we can use `scanf()` function without using stdio.h

**Example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char str [80];
  scanf ("%s",str);  
  return 0;
}
```

The above code can be written as

```
extern int scanf(const char *format, ...);

int main ()
{
  char str [80];
  scanf ("%s",str);  
  return 0;
}
```

Here by calling `extern int scanf(const char *format, ...);`, `scanf()` will work seamlessly.

I am a trainer, my students asked me about this weird doubt and its my reason. I need to how it can be achieved with some code, just like `extern int scanf(const char *format, ...);` for replacing `stdio.h`

Comment: If you can do it in c, then you can in c++. You would be limited to very small programs. You should know that the only reason why you can do that at all is because you're still linking to the libraries that have those methods. Most importantly, what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: When analyzing a program the first task is to identify the requirements of the program. After the program requirements are identified then the program can be coded to meet those requirements. In this case, you simply want to do something. What is the requirement that drives this question?

Comment: If you don't want to use system API or run time lib, There is another way to achive your requirement, write a coustom run time lib for yourself

Comment: So run your source file through the preprocessor. There. all the hard work done for you. And as a bonus you get all the details for your implementation for free.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using printf function without actually importing stdio.h and it worked?! Why is that so?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150883/using-printf-function-without-actually-importing-stdio-h-and-it-worked-why-is)

Comment: @aaronman I added my reason for this question

Comment: Also, C ***XOR*** C++? There's no such language as "C/C++".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the reasons behind your question but there is a (very ugly) way.

Simply use your preprocessor (and not the compiler) with the right options (which depend on your environment) and it will generate a header-free equivalent CPP file which can be compiled.

Doing the same thing manually is just very prone to errors... and in my opinion completely useless.

Below is an example based on provided code in the question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char str [80];
      scanf ("%s",str);
        return 0;
}
```

Using the command `gcc -E main.cpp|grep -v "^#" |grep -v "^$"` i extracted the following code (note that lines starting with # and empty lines were removed by my grep commands) :

```
extern "C" {
typedef unsigned int size_t;
typedef unsigned char __u_char;
typedef unsigned short int __u_short;
typedef unsigned int __u_int;
typedef unsigned long int __u_long;
typedef signed char __int8_t;
typedef unsigned char __uint8_t;
typedef signed short int __int16_t;
typedef unsigned short int __uint16_t;
typedef signed int __int32_t;
typedef unsigned int __uint32_t;
__extension__ typedef signed long long int __int64_t;
__extension__ typedef unsigned long long int __uint64_t;
__extension__ typedef long long int __quad_t;
__extension__ typedef unsigned long long int __u_quad_t;
__extension__ typedef __u_quad_t __dev_t;
__extension__ typedef unsigned int __uid_t;
__extension__ typedef unsigned int __gid_t;
__extension__ typedef unsigned long int __ino_t;
__extension__ typedef __u_quad_t __ino64_t;
__extension__ typedef unsigned int __mode_t;
__extension__ typedef unsigned int __nlink_t;
__extension__ typedef long int __off_t;
__extension__ typedef __quad_t __off64_t;
__extension__ typedef int __pid_t;
__extension__ typedef struct { int __val[2]; } __fsid_t;
__extension__ typedef long int __clock_t;
__extension__ typedef unsigned long int __rlim_t;
__extension__ typedef __u_quad_t __rlim64_t;
__extension__ typedef unsigned int __id_t;
__extension__ typedef long int __time_t;
__extension__ typedef unsigned int __useconds_t;
__extension__ typedef long int __suseconds_t;
__extension__ typedef int __daddr_t;
__extension__ typedef long int __swblk_t;
__extension__ typedef int __key_t;
__extension__ typedef int __clockid_t;
__extension__ typedef void * __timer_t;
__extension__ typedef long int __blksize_t;
__extension__ typedef long int __blkcnt_t;
__extension__ typedef __quad_t __blkcnt64_t;
__extension__ typedef unsigned long int __fsblkcnt_t;
__extension__ typedef __u_quad_t __fsblkcnt64_t;
__extension__ typedef unsigned long int __fsfilcnt_t;
__extension__ typedef __u_quad_t __fsfilcnt64_t;
__extension__ typedef int __ssize_t;
typedef __off64_t __loff_t;
typedef __quad_t *__qaddr_t;
typedef char *__caddr_t;
__extension__ typedef int __intptr_t;
__extension__ typedef unsigned int __socklen_t;
struct _IO_FILE;
typedef struct _IO_FILE FILE;
typedef struct _IO_FILE __FILE;
typedef struct
{
  int __count;
  union
  {
    unsigned int __wch;
    char __wchb[4];
  } __value;
} __mbstate_t;
typedef struct
{
  __off_t __pos;
  __mbstate_t __state;
} _G_fpos_t;
typedef struct
{
  __off64_t __pos;
  __mbstate_t __state;
} _G_fpos64_t;
typedef int _G_int16_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__HI__)));
typedef int _G_int32_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__SI__)));
typedef unsigned int _G_uint16_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__HI__)));
typedef unsigned int _G_uint32_t __attribute__ ((__mode__ (__SI__)));
typedef __builtin_va_list __gnuc_va_list;
struct _IO_jump_t; struct _IO_FILE;
typedef void _IO_lock_t;
struct _IO_marker {
  struct _IO_marker *_next;
  struct _IO_FILE *_sbuf;
  int _pos;
};
enum __codecvt_result
{
  __codecvt_ok,
  __codecvt_partial,
  __codecvt_error,
  __codecvt_noconv
};
struct _IO_FILE {
  int _flags;
  char* _IO_read_ptr;
  char* _IO_read_end;
  char* _IO_read_base;
  char* _IO_write_base;
  char* _IO_write_ptr;
  char* _IO_write_end;
  char* _IO_buf_base;
  char* _IO_buf_end;
  char *_IO_save_base;
  char *_IO_backup_base;
  char *_IO_save_end;
  struct _IO_marker *_markers;
  struct _IO_FILE *_chain;
  int _fileno;
  int _flags2;
  __off_t _old_offset;
  unsigned short _cur_column;
  signed char _vtable_offset;
  char _shortbuf[1];
  _IO_lock_t *_lock;
  __off64_t _offset;
  void *__pad1;
  void *__pad2;
  void *__pad3;
  void *__pad4;
  size_t __pad5;
  int _mode;
  char _unused2[15 * sizeof (int) - 4 * sizeof (void *) - sizeof (size_t)];
};
struct _IO_FILE_plus;
extern struct _IO_FILE_plus _IO_2_1_stdin_;
extern struct _IO_FILE_plus _IO_2_1_stdout_;
extern struct _IO_FILE_plus _IO_2_1_stderr_;
typedef __ssize_t __io_read_fn (void *__cookie, char *__buf, size_t __nbytes);
typedef __ssize_t __io_write_fn (void *__cookie, __const char *__buf,
     size_t __n);
typedef int __io_seek_fn (void *__cookie, __off64_t *__pos, int __w);
typedef int __io_close_fn (void *__cookie);
typedef __io_read_fn cookie_read_function_t;
typedef __io_write_fn cookie_write_function_t;
typedef __io_seek_fn cookie_seek_function_t;
typedef __io_close_fn cookie_close_function_t;
typedef struct
{
  __io_read_fn *read;
  __io_write_fn *write;
  __io_seek_fn *seek;
  __io_close_fn *close;
} _IO_cookie_io_functions_t;
typedef _IO_cookie_io_functions_t cookie_io_functions_t;
struct _IO_cookie_file;
extern void _IO_cookie_init (struct _IO_cookie_file *__cfile, int __read_write,
        void *__cookie, _IO_cookie_io_functions_t __fns);
extern "C" {
extern int __underflow (_IO_FILE *);
extern int __uflow (_IO_FILE *);
extern int __overflow (_IO_FILE *, int);
extern int _IO_getc (_IO_FILE *__fp);
extern int _IO_putc (int __c, _IO_FILE *__fp);
extern int _IO_feof (_IO_FILE *__fp) throw ();
extern int _IO_ferror (_IO_FILE *__fp) throw ();
extern int _IO_peekc_locked (_IO_FILE *__fp);
extern void _IO_flockfile (_IO_FILE *) throw ();
extern void _IO_funlockfile (_IO_FILE *) throw ();
extern int _IO_ftrylockfile (_IO_FILE *) throw ();
extern int _IO_vfscanf (_IO_FILE * __restrict, const char * __restrict,
   __gnuc_va_list, int *__restrict);
extern int _IO_vfprintf (_IO_FILE *__restrict, const char *__restrict,
    __gnuc_va_list);
extern __ssize_t _IO_padn (_IO_FILE *, int, __ssize_t);
extern size_t _IO_sgetn (_IO_FILE *, void *, size_t);
extern __off64_t _IO_seekoff (_IO_FILE *, __off64_t, int, int);
extern __off64_t _IO_seekpos (_IO_FILE *, __off64_t, int);
extern void _IO_free_backup_area (_IO_FILE *) throw ();
}
typedef __gnuc_va_list va_list;
typedef __off_t off_t;
typedef __off64_t off64_t;
typedef __ssize_t ssize_t;
typedef _G_fpos_t fpos_t;
typedef _G_fpos64_t fpos64_t;
extern struct _IO_FILE *stdin;
extern struct _IO_FILE *stdout;
extern struct _IO_FILE *stderr;
extern int remove (__const char *__filename) throw ();
extern int rename (__const char *__old, __const char *__new) throw ();
extern int renameat (int __oldfd, __const char *__old, int __newfd,
       __const char *__new) throw ();
extern FILE *tmpfile (void) ;
extern FILE *tmpfile64 (void) ;
extern char *tmpnam (char *__s) throw () ;
extern char *tmpnam_r (char *__s) throw () ;
extern char *tempnam (__const char *__dir, __const char *__pfx)
     throw () __attribute__ ((__malloc__)) ;
extern int fclose (FILE *__stream);
extern int fflush (FILE *__stream);
extern int fflush_unlocked (FILE *__stream);
extern int fcloseall (void);
extern FILE *fopen (__const char *__restrict __filename,
      __const char *__restrict __modes) ;
extern FILE *freopen (__const char *__restrict __filename,
        __const char *__restrict __modes,
        FILE *__restrict __stream) ;
extern FILE *fopen64 (__const char *__restrict __filename,
        __const char *__restrict __modes) ;
extern FILE *freopen64 (__const char *__restrict __filename,
   __const char *__restrict __modes,
   FILE *__restrict __stream) ;
extern FILE *fdopen (int __fd, __const char *__modes) throw () ;
extern FILE *fopencookie (void *__restrict __magic_cookie,
     __const char *__restrict __modes,
     _IO_cookie_io_functions_t __io_funcs) throw () ;
extern FILE *fmemopen (void *__s, size_t __len, __const char *__modes)
  throw () ;
extern FILE *open_memstream (char **__bufloc, size_t *__sizeloc) throw () ;
extern void setbuf (FILE *__restrict __stream, char *__restrict __buf) throw ();
extern int setvbuf (FILE *__restrict __stream, char *__restrict __buf,
      int __modes, size_t __n) throw ();
extern void setbuffer (FILE *__restrict __stream, char *__restrict __buf,
         size_t __size) throw ();
extern void setlinebuf (FILE *__stream) throw ();
extern int fprintf (FILE *__restrict __stream,
      __const char *__restrict __format, ...);
extern int printf (__const char *__restrict __format, ...);
extern int sprintf (char *__restrict __s,
      __const char *__restrict __format, ...) throw ();
extern int vfprintf (FILE *__restrict __s, __const char *__restrict __format,
       __gnuc_va_list __arg);
extern int vprintf (__const char *__restrict __format, __gnuc_va_list __arg);
extern int vsprintf (char *__restrict __s, __const char *__restrict __format,
       __gnuc_va_list __arg) throw ();
extern int snprintf (char *__restrict __s, size_t __maxlen,
       __const char *__restrict __format, ...)
     throw () __attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 3, 4)));
extern int vsnprintf (char *__restrict __s, size_t __maxlen,
        __const char *__restrict __format, __gnuc_va_list __arg)
     throw () __attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 3, 0)));
extern int vasprintf (char **__restrict __ptr, __const char *__restrict __f,
        __gnuc_va_list __arg)
     throw () __attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 0))) ;
extern int __asprintf (char **__restrict __ptr,
         __const char *__restrict __fmt, ...)
     throw () __attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 3))) ;
extern int asprintf (char **__restrict __ptr,
       __const char *__restrict __fmt, ...)
     throw () __attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 3))) ;
extern int vdprintf (int __fd, __const char *__restrict __fmt,
       __gnuc_va_list __arg)
     __attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 0)));
extern int dprintf (int __fd, __const char *__restrict __fmt, ...)
     __attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 3)));
extern int fscanf (FILE *__restrict __stream,
     __const char *__restrict __format, ...) ;
extern int scanf (__const char *__restrict __format, ...) ;
extern int sscanf (__const char *__restrict __s,
     __const char *__restrict __format, ...) throw ();
extern int vfscanf (FILE *__restrict __s, __const char *__restrict __format,
      __gnuc_va_list __arg)
     __attribute__ ((__format__ (__scanf__, 2, 0))) ;
extern int vscanf (__const char *__restrict __format, __gnuc_va_list __arg)
     __attribute__ ((__format__ (__scanf__, 1, 0))) ;
extern int vsscanf (__const char *__restrict __s,
      __const char *__restrict __format, __gnuc_va_list __arg)
     throw () __attribute__ ((__format__ (__scanf__, 2, 0)));
extern int fgetc (FILE *__stream);
extern int getc (FILE *__stream);
extern int getchar (void);
extern int getc_unlocked (FILE *__stream);
extern int getchar_unlocked (void);
extern int fgetc_unlocked (FILE *__stream);
extern int fputc (int __c, FILE *__stream);
extern int putc (int __c, FILE *__stream);
extern int putchar (int __c);
extern int fputc_unlocked (int __c, FILE *__stream);
extern int putc_unlocked (int __c, FILE *__stream);
extern int putchar_unlocked (int __c);
extern int getw (FILE *__stream);
extern int putw (int __w, FILE *__stream);
extern char *fgets (char *__restrict __s, int __n, FILE *__restrict __stream)
     ;
extern char *gets (char *__s) ;
extern char *fgets_unlocked (char *__restrict __s, int __n,
        FILE *__restrict __stream) ;
extern __ssize_t __getdelim (char **__restrict __lineptr,
          size_t *__restrict __n, int __delimiter,
          FILE *__restrict __stream) ;
extern __ssize_t getdelim (char **__restrict __lineptr,
        size_t *__restrict __n, int __delimiter,
        FILE *__restrict __stream) ;
extern __ssize_t getline (char **__restrict __lineptr,
       size_t *__restrict __n,
       FILE *__restrict __stream) ;
extern int fputs (__const char *__restrict __s, FILE *__restrict __stream);
extern int puts (__const char *__s);
extern int ungetc (int __c, FILE *__stream);
extern size_t fread (void *__restrict __ptr, size_t __size,
       size_t __n, FILE *__restrict __stream) ;
extern size_t fwrite (__const void *__restrict __ptr, size_t __size,
        size_t __n, FILE *__restrict __s);
extern int fputs_unlocked (__const char *__restrict __s,
      FILE *__restrict __stream);
extern size_t fread_unlocked (void *__restrict __ptr, size_t __size,
         size_t __n, FILE *__restrict __stream) ;
extern size_t fwrite_unlocked (__const void *__restrict __ptr, size_t __size,
          size_t __n, FILE *__restrict __stream);
extern int fseek (FILE *__stream, long int __off, int __whence);
extern long int ftell (FILE *__stream) ;
extern void rewind (FILE *__stream);
extern int fseeko (FILE *__stream, __off_t __off, int __whence);
extern __off_t ftello (FILE *__stream) ;
extern int fgetpos (FILE *__restrict __stream, fpos_t *__restrict __pos);
extern int fsetpos (FILE *__stream, __const fpos_t *__pos);
extern int fseeko64 (FILE *__stream, __off64_t __off, int __whence);
extern __off64_t ftello64 (FILE *__stream) ;
extern int fgetpos64 (FILE *__restrict __stream, fpos64_t *__restrict __pos);
extern int fsetpos64 (FILE *__stream, __const fpos64_t *__pos);
extern void clearerr (FILE *__stream) throw ();
extern int feof (FILE *__stream) throw () ;
extern int ferror (FILE *__stream) throw () ;
extern void clearerr_unlocked (FILE *__stream) throw ();
extern int feof_unlocked (FILE *__stream) throw () ;
extern int ferror_unlocked (FILE *__stream) throw () ;
extern void perror (__const char *__s);
extern int sys_nerr;
extern __const char *__const sys_errlist[];
extern int _sys_nerr;
extern __const char *__const _sys_errlist[];
extern int fileno (FILE *__stream) throw () ;
extern int fileno_unlocked (FILE *__stream) throw () ;
extern FILE *popen (__const char *__command, __const char *__modes) ;
extern int pclose (FILE *__stream);
extern char *ctermid (char *__s) throw ();
extern char *cuserid (char *__s);
struct obstack;
extern int obstack_printf (struct obstack *__restrict __obstack,
      __const char *__restrict __format, ...)
     throw () __attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 3)));
extern int obstack_vprintf (struct obstack *__restrict __obstack,
       __const char *__restrict __format,
       __gnuc_va_list __args)
     throw () __attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 2, 0)));
extern void flockfile (FILE *__stream) throw ();
extern int ftrylockfile (FILE *__stream) throw () ;
extern void funlockfile (FILE *__stream) throw ();
}
int main ()
{
    char str [80];
      scanf ("%s",str);
        return 0;
}
```

Yes, it does hurt the eye a bit...

Comment: I also think the same way, but please include some examples in your answer

Comment: I need some sample codes, I will accept your answer if you have relevant sample code

Comment: the above code can be simply written 

`extern int scanf(const char *format, ...);

int main ()
{
  char str [80];
  scanf ("%s",str);  
  return 0;
}`

Comment: It is important to note that large chunks of the C++ library are headers with templated classes, which means there isn't an implementation in cpp file to link against. You'll end up just inlining the entire header into every file that needs it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Remember, that `#include` reads the file and puts it literally in the place of this compiler directive. So you can simply manually copy contents of `stdio.h` and other headers to your `cpp` file and append your code at the bottom.

Not recommended, though ;)

---

**Edit:** In response to comments:

Here you go: http://pastebin.com/QG7MM3a7

Comment: @Niko I've included the example. I guess though, that it can be a lot shorter. Please be advised, that such code is very platform-specific and this method (being pointless anyway) is not recommended to be used.

Answer (score 3):

The C11 standard, §7.1.4/2 guarantees:

> Provided that a library function can be declared without reference to any type defined in a header, it is also permissible to declare the function and use it without including its associated header.

Your program is thus valid input to anything that advertises itself as compatible with the C programming language.

It is true that any such system is also guaranteed to declare `printf` inside `stdio.h`, so it would be much easier (and more obvious) to use `#include`.

But including a header also has side effects that may be undesirable: in C, it causes the identifiers declared by the header to become reserved as macro names. (So you can do `#define printf foo` *only* if you do not include `<stdio.h>`.) In C++, including any standard header causes all identifiers which are keywords, or are defined in any standard header, to become reserved as macro names. (In C, I cannot find in the standard what forbids you from something like `#define while 42`, but there is probably something equivalent.)

So, if you want permission to go crazy redefining keywords to other things, feel free to write programs that way. But, nobody will be willing to help you, except perhaps compiler authors who care deeply about compliance, but we tend to prefer complaints to be stated in precise legalese. Without being able to do that, your situation would become that nobody will help or work with you.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes

Long answer: Yes, but you probably won't gain much because you will end up duplicating most of the work yourself.

Header files, like stdio.h, usually provide lots of function *declarations*.  Note that declarations are not *definitions*.  Declarations merely tell the compiler to trust that the function exists (and allow you to call it), while definitions provide the code for the function itself.

You are providing a declaration for scanf(), so the compiler allows you to call it.  However, the stdio.h header already provides a declaration for scanf, so you don't really gain a whole lot.  Furthermore, the only reason that this *just works* is because the definition for scanf() happens to already exist in your executable --- most likely because it is a library function and your compiler automatically includes that library.  If it had not included the library that contains scanf(), the linker (which runs after the compiler) would have complained and given you an error along the lines of "undefined reference to scanf()...".

So, you can avoid using the standard headers by providing declarations for all of the library functions you wish to use, but you must be careful that the declarations you provide match up exactly with what is contained in the library (else you may get unresolved symbol/reference errors from the linker).  This is in fact the job of most headers --- they act as 'contracts' between different modules of code.  In this case, the stdio.h header is a 'contract' for some of the functions provided by the standard libraries: it allows you to call them by providing declarations, but furthermore, it implicitly claims that the definitions for those functions exist somewhere.

With all that in mind, do you really want to avoid including the headers and having to manually pick and choose which functions you declare (while simultaneously cross-checking to make sure you got the declaration right)?

**Edit**: I may have misunderstood the purpose of the question.  Yes, you should be able to write nearly any program and use nearly all APIs without actually including a header, but you will have to tediously cross-check all of your declarations to make sure that they are correct.  You will also lose out on any inline definitions provided by headers for optimization.