# How to get warnings from missing header files?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am working in a C program in Code::Blocks. I am using the function `printf` and I am not including the `<stdio.h>` header however the program runs well. How do I enable warning to not miss the header?

Thank you in advance for your time and help,

Comment: Did you set warning flags? I don't know how it is done in CodeBlocks, but should be somewhere in the project properties. I recommend "-Wall -Wextra -pedantic"

Comment: Are you including some other header file that already includes stdio.h?

Comment: @Dai it works well without stdio... http://ideone.com/LpAs5P

Comment: Maybe it's because you're using old C compiler? According to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/336825/6131611 answer, newest C standard (C99) doesn't allow use functions in this way

Comment: It'd be helpful if you show your code.

Comment: If you're using GCC, you could add options like `-Wmissing-prototypes`, `-Wstrict-prototypes`, `-Wold-style-declaration`, `-Wold-style-definition` (along with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`, and maybe `-pedantic`, and sometimes `-Wshadow` and … well, there are a lot of possibilities).  The `-Wmissing-prototypes` will trigger complaints if `printf()` is not declared.  The `-Wstrict-prototypes` won't allow `int main() { … }` (neither will `-Wold-style-definition`), requiring `int main(void) { … }`.  I compile with those options set all the time.

Comment: What @Dai meant was that you might have included stdio without explicitly doing it. It might be included by another header file, which you did include

Comment: Does flags written by Jonathan work?

Comment: why you don't write answer guys?